# Oxford journal referencing style

Tags: formatting, stylesheet, cdf-format, style

I've been scanning through Mathematica documentation for a while but has been unable to find anything related to compiling a journal/ report based on Oxford style. 
Does Mathematica have this option or is Microsoft word the only tool that would allow this?

Help is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please link or explain what 'Oxford style' is.